# What's the difference between StateT s (ExceptT e m) and ExceptT e (StateT s m)?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Monad transformers are tricky, and I'm not sure (= don't have good intuition) which one should go on top.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457111/how-to-design-a-monadic-stack)

Comment: @luqui Didn't find that. Yet I'd like to keep this question: at least it's much narrower in scope, so can be answered better.

Comment: By the way, lambdabot has a monad-stack-unroller. Try `?unmtl` in the #haskell channel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
StateT s (ExceptT e m)
```

This says:

- Start with `m`
- Add exceptions to that
- Add state to that

Now, 'adding exceptions' means your actions can terminate in two ways: either with a normal return value, or with an exception.

'Adding state' means that an extra bit of state output gets included in *the normal return values*.

So in `StateT s (ExceptT e m)`, you only get a result state if there is no exception.

On the other hand,

```
ExceptT e (StateT s m)
```

says:

- Start with `m`
- Add state to that
- Add exceptions to that

'Adding state' means that an extra bit of state output gets included in the return values of `m`.

But now, your added exceptions get added as an alternative return value *inside the `StateT` monad*.  So you always get a state output, and then you may get a normal return value or you may get an exception along with it.

Comment: This might give a more immediately clear picture, so: `StateT s (ExceptT e m) a` has the "expanded" form: `s -> m (Either e (s, a))` whilst `ExceptT e (StateT s m)` "expands" to: `s -> m (s, Either e a)`. The former allows you to roll-back changes to the state when an error occurs in `catchError`, while the latter commits faulty states making them harder to rollback. In some languages you actually want the latter. Recommended reading: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/TDA342_Advanced_Functional_Programming/lecture8.html

Answer (score 12):

I answer this myself, but other answers are welcome!

Consider the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack runghc --package mtl 

{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Main (main) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Functor.Identity

test1 :: (MonadState Int m, MonadError String m) => m Bool
test1 = do
  put 1
  throwError "foobar"
  put 2
  return False

test2 :: (Alternative m, MonadState Int m, MonadError String m) => m Bool
test2 = do
  put 4
  test1 <|> return True

runStateExceptT :: Monad m => s -> ExceptT e (StateT s m) a -> m (Either e a, s)
runStateExceptT s = flip runStateT s . runExceptT

runExceptStateT :: Monad m => s -> StateT s (ExceptT e m) a -> m (Either e (a, s))
runExceptStateT s = runExceptT . flip runStateT s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ runIdentity . runStateExceptT 3 $ test1
  print $ runIdentity . runExceptStateT 3 $ test1
  print $ runIdentity . runStateExceptT 3 $ test2
  print $ runIdentity . runExceptStateT 3 $ test2
```

It will print:

```
(Left "foobar",1)
Left "foobar"
(Right True,1)
Right (True,4)
```

With `ExceptT` outside, you'll still get the state which was at the moment of "throwing an error". This is probably what you want.

Remember that this combination resembles imperative programming *a lot*. One should think about exception safety practicies, i.e. must be careful about when to `throwError`!