# How to combine Option and Result

Tags: f#

I find myself returning type `Option<Result<'a,'b>>` a lot, my reasoning is the following:

I use Option to decide if I'm interested in processing an event, and if I do, then I return a result of processing it.

Is there a proper name for this pattern? And better operators? For example, I use: `Option.map(Result.map f)` is there an operator for mapping nested functors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call it a monadic stack.

You can define your own operators, but if you want to map them, you need something like a "deep map level 2" which normally is `(map >> map)` so, in this case:

```
Some (Result<int,string>.Ok 1) |> (Result.map >> Option.map) ((+) 1)
// val it : Result<int,string> option = Some (Ok 2)
```

If you want to explore more [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) provides limited support for this through 2 different abstractions:

- Composed functors: by using the `Compose` type from `FSharpPlus.Data`:

```
let v1 = Compose (Some (Result<int,string>.Ok 1)) 
let v2 = v1 |> map ((+) 1)
// .. more operations, then when you're finished ..
let v3 = Compose.run v2

// val v1 : Compose<Result<int,string> option> = Compose (Some (Ok 1))
// val v2 : Compose<Result<int,string> option> = Compose (Some (Ok 2))
// val v3 : Result<int,string> option = Some (Ok 2)
```

So it allows you to compose arbitrary Functors, which are types you can map on.

- Monad transformers: by using in this particular case the `ResultT` type from `FSharpPlus.Data`:

The previous example would work, just replace `Compose` for `ResultT`, but now you can also do monadic operations:

```
let x = monad' {
    let! v1 = ResultT (Some (Result<int,string>.Ok 1))
    let! v2 = ResultT (Some (Result<int,string>.Ok 1))
    return v1 + v2 }
ResultT.run x

// val x : ResultT<Result<int,string> option> = ResultT (Some (Ok 2))
// val it : Result<int,string> option = Some (Ok 2)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! now I can properly search this pattern, like for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485344/9130688. those figures are exactly how I see my code, amazed.

Answer (score 11):

I think the existing answer from Gus answers your question about the name of the pattern. In Haskell, this is achieved using *monad transformers* and the F#+ library lets you do this in F# too.

However, this pattern is not very common in most F# code. One reason is that it leads to very complicated code (both the types get complex and the processing code gets pretty cumbersome).

If you find yourself using `Option<Result<'T>>` often, then I would consider if it makes sense to define a new type for this, perhaps using names that makes sense in your domain, so that the reader of the code can easily understand it. You could use something like:

```
type ProcessingResult<'T> = 
  | Ignored
  | Failed of string
  | Accepted of 'T
```

You will lose built-in functions for `Option` and `Result`, but you can implement the ones you need yourself. It is not too complicated:

```
module Processing =
  let map f = function
    | Ignored -> Ignored
    | Failed s -> Failed s
    | Accepted v -> Accepted (f v)
```

The benefit of this is that `Processing.map` is much easier to read, which I think is a trade-off worth making.

Comment: Thank you! I always write it in Choice1Of3 at some point but end up going back to `Option<Result<'a,'b>` because it has a better composition; I always reject the idea of creating a DU because then I have to deal with the branches in the intermediary fns, but if I reimplement `map` for example, that wouldn't be a problem and would be more concrete, thank you for your input, I'll try this approach to see how it turns out too.