# Monad transformer loop failing when the short circuit happens on the first run

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have a RWST in haskell over a Maybe, which short circuits under certain conditions. I want to run this action until it returns Nothing, and get the last Just. So my situation is as follows;

```
type St = MyState
type Re = MyRead
type Wr = MyWriter
type Foo = RWST Re Wr St Maybe

action :: Foo ()
```

The only way that I thought of for achieving that, is by defining the following;

```
run = action >> run <|> action
```

which has the downside that if the short circuiting happens on the  <s>first</s>  second run, even though there is an output, I get Nothing because `run` runs the action twice. Is there any better way of looping? I looked into `extra` but the functions supplied there do not help my cause.

---

So, after considering the answers given, and trying everything out, it seems the easiest solution is to use `many`. In the general case though, swapping for a MaybeT as suggested is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking over your question and going back and forth about whether this answer applies to your situation.  Really I can't tell without more context, so I'll just leave it here in case.

You are using `Maybe` as the base monad, and that might not be what you want.  I want to forget about the reader and writer part of `RWST` for a moment and pretend we are just using `StateT`, because it simpler, but the same idea applies (`StateT` is basically the same thing as `RWST () ()` after all).  The definition of `StateT` is:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT (s -> m (a, s))
```

So, after all is unrolled and done, the type of `run` ends up as

```
run :: St -> Maybe ((), St)
```

You give it an `St`, and it gives you back either a pair with a resulting `St` in it, or `Nothing`.  In particular, when it "fails" (as in, returns `Nothing`), the failure does not come with a resulting state, so all state changes prior to the failure are forgotten.  That means if you ever take the right side of `(<|>)`, anything that happened in the left side doesn't matter anymore, the only influence it has on the result is the fact that it failed.  But the fact that you want to do this in a loop betrays that you want to keep the state changes after failure.

That is what [`MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) is for.  Put the `MaybeT` on the *outside*.  `MaybeT` is defined as

```
 newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT (m (Maybe a))
```

So if your monad were `MaybeT (State St)`, the implementation type would be

```
 run :: St -> (Maybe (), St)
```

Notice that now, whether the action succeeds or fails, we get an `St` out the other end.  This will allow `(<|>)` to carry on manipulating the state that its left side changed rather than starting anew, which I'm guessing is your intention (though I can't say for sure).

In general, the inner monads of a transformer chain are more powerful -- a transformer are always subject to the rules of their inner monad.  The "primary" effect of `StateT s Maybe` is that it either succeeds with a value or fails outright, and then the statefulness has to be "emulated" on top of that.  Whereas the primary effect of `MaybeT (State s)` is that of statefulness -- no matter what `MaybeT` does, there is always a single state carried through the computation.  [More on transformer stack design here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457111/how-to-design-a-monadic-stack).

Comment: MonadPlus instance of Maybe holds the leftmost Just, that is why I run the action and sequence it with the recursive call on the left, so in any case apart from the case where the Nothing is thrown on the second run, everything works. I will try your solution, seems interesting.

Comment: @Jason, if you can phrase your problem as a simple `f :: a -> Maybe a` and want to repeat it until the the last `a` that doesn't result in `Nothing`, you can use `last . catMaybes $ iterate (f =<<) (pure initialState)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pure ()` as the base case:

```
run = action >> run <|> pure ()
```

This is also known as `many` from Control.Applicative:

```
run = many action
```

Comment: Doesn't this yield `()` as the value, rather than the value returned by `action`?

Comment: @amalloy the type of action is `Foo ()`, so it can only return `()` (or bottom).

Comment: the return type is () as you mentioned, but in Foo () I am actually interested in the change in state after the loop.

Comment: @Jason, I see, in that case you'd indeed need to change the order of the maybe and state transformers as luqui suggests.